# Removing everything after specific character in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, substring

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "s=DIR D:\MyFolder /S /Q ^|FIND /i "Owner" ^|findstr /m /i "\.mkv$""
for /f "Tokens=5,6*" %%a in ('%s%') do (
SET _endbit=%%aa:*STRING=%
CALL SET _result=%%aa:%_endbit%=%%
>>%tmp%\list.txt echo %_result% %%b %%c
)
wscript "C:\my.vbs"
```

I am listing my files that owned by Owner and has extension mkv from MyFolder. I want to remove everything after specific character/word. I wrote that code. But It seems to be not working.

First of all, is it possible to do that? If so what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You came up with the same solution I was going to post on your other question - but I think you're missing some things. The line ending `STRING=%` is missing another `%` at the end, and the line `%%aa:%_endbit%=%%`, I'm not sure it can work directly on the variable from the `for` loop, and you need to store it in another variable first, and you probably need some expansions using `!` characters too.

Here's what I had that seems to work, just as a test in a folder with three files in it, removing the end of the filename using `E0` as the cutoff string:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off

for %%f in (*.mkv) do (
    set FULLNAME=%%f
    set ENDTEXT=!FULLNAME:*E0=!
    call set TRIMMEDNAME=%%FULLNAME:!ENDTEXT!=%%
    echo !TRIMMEDNAME!
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes now its working. Is it possible to change E0 to E0* . I mean It could be E04 E08 E09 E19 * is variable.

Comment: I can't think of a way, unless you make the string `S01E` and leave nothing after it, or start bringing in an external program like `sed` for Windows. The syntax `%var:*str1=%` is only supported with the asterisk at the start, there's no way to add the `*` to the end, that's why we have to do the pattern of getting the bit we don't want, storing it, then using that as the bit to get rid of. (This whole thing would be much easier in PowerShell, by the way).